# Getting llvm-rs-cc.exe error in Android Studio

Tags: android

Getting an error when compiling with RenderScript library:

> llvm-rs-cc.exe  finished with non-zero exit value -1073741515.

I know there is similar thread about the same question but I didn't find any solution out of the answers provided. I searched thoroughly on internet but there is nothing I can find about it.

It will be great if someone helps.

Comment: Can you list the global variables you have? Also, are you generating java reflection code? You might try to narrow down the cause of the problem in your source code by selective enable/disable by commenting for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Build-Tools 23.0.2 or before on Windows?
There was a bug about incorrect packaging dependencies in the old windows Build-Tools.

The fix is also simple, just use buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" or later.